# How to re-enable Chrome pop blocker

Tags: google-chrome, popup

I need to write something to alert the user if the popup blocker is on for Chrome...Unfortunately I have already set chrome to allow popups from the site.  So now I can't get the popup blocker.  How do I turn it back on so the popup blocker actually works again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it, Under chrome menu -> Settings -> Show advanced settings -> (Under Privacy) content settings -> ( under pop up section) manage exceptions